Celery Error: "Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable"
Description:
I'm currently working on a genetic algorithm implementation using Celery for asynchronous task execution. I have three main files in my project: tasks.py, genetic_algorithms_functions.py, and genetic_algorithm_trial.py. The goal of the project is to optimize routes based on a distance matrix
I'm encountering an error when trying to retrieve the initial population asynchronously using Celery's get() method in the genetic_algorithm_trial.py file. Here's the specific error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genetic_algorithm_trial.py", line 23, in <module>
    initial_population = initial_population_task.get()
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "celery/result.py", line 251, in get
    return self.backend.wait_for_pending(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 223, in wait_for_pending
    return result.maybe_throw(callback=callback, propagate=propagate)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "celery/result.py", line 365, in maybe_throw
    self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb))
  File "celery/result.py", line 358, in throw
    self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "vine/promises.py", line 235, in throw
    reraise(type(exc), exc, tb)
  File "vine/utils.py", line 27, in reraise
    raise value
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: TypeError('Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable')

Files:
1.tasks.py
# tasks.py

from celery import Celery
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from genetic_algorithms_functions import calculate_fitness, select_in_tournament, order_crossover, mutate, generate_unique_population

app = Celery('tasks',
         broker='redis://localhost',
         backend='redis://localhost')

# Load the distance matrix
distance_matrix = pd.read_csv('city_distances.csv').to_numpy()

@app.task
def evaluate_fitness(route):
    return calculate_fitness(route, distance_matrix)

@app.task
def run_tournament_selection(population, scores):
    return select_in_tournament(population, scores)

@app.task
def perform_order_crossover(parent1, parent2):
    return order_crossover(parent1, parent2)

@app.task
def perform_mutation(route, mutation_rate):
    return mutate(route, mutation_rate)

@app.task
def generate_initial_population(population_size, num_nodes):
    return generate_unique_population(population_size, num_nodes)


2.genetic_algorithms_function.py:
import numpy as np


def calculate_fitness(route, distance_matrix):
    """
    Calculate the total distance traveled by the car.

    Parameters:
        - route (list): A list representing the order of nodes visited in the route.
        - distance_matrix (numpy.ndarray): A matrix of the distances between nodes.
            A 2D numpy array where the element at position [i, j] represents the 
            distance between node i and node j.
    Returns:
        - float: The negative total distance traveled 
          (negative because we want to minimize distance).
          Returns a large negative penalty if the route is infeasible.
    """
    total_distance = 0
    route = np.array(route)  # Convert route to numpy array
    for i in range(len(route) - 1):
        total_distance += distance_matrix[route[i]][route[i + 1]]
    total_distance += distance_matrix[route[-1]][route[0]]
    return float(-total_distance)  # Convert the result to float before returning




def select_in_tournament(population, scores, number_tournaments=4, tournament_size=3):
    """
    Tournament selection for genetic algorithm.

    Parameters:
        - population (list): The current population of routes.
        - scores (np.array): The calculate_fitness scores corresponding to each individual in the population.
        - number_tournaments (int): The number of tournaments to run in the population.
        - tournament_size (int): The number of individuals to compete in each tournament.

    Returns:
        - list: A list of selected individuals for crossover.
    """
    selected = []

    for _ in range(number_tournaments):
        # Randomly select tournament_size individuals from the population
        idx = np.random.choice(len(population), tournament_size, replace=False)
        
        # Find the index of the individual with the highest fitness score among the selected individuals
        best_idx = np.argmax(scores[idx])
        
        # Store the index of the best individual
        selected.append(population[idx[best_idx]])
    
    return selected


def order_crossover(parent1, parent2):
    """
    Order crossover (OX) for permutations.

    Parameters:
        - parent1 (list): The first parent route.
        - parent2 (list): The second parent route.

    Returns:
        - list: The offspring route generated by the crossover.
    """
    size = len(parent1)
    start, end = sorted(np.random.choice(range(size), 2, replace=False))
    offspring = [None] * size
    offspring[start:end + 1] = parent1[start:end + 1]
    fill_values = [x for x in parent2 if x not in offspring[start:end + 1]]
    idx = 0
    for i in range(size):
        if offspring[i] is None:
            offspring[i] = fill_values[idx]
            idx += 1
    return offspring


def mutate(route,
           mutation_rate = 0.1):
    """
    Mutation operator: swap two nodes in the route.

    Parameters:
        - route (list): The route to mutate.
        - mutation_rate (float): The chance to mutate an individual.
    Returns:
        - list: The mutated route.
    """
    if np.random.rand() < mutation_rate:
        i, j = np.random.choice(len(route), 2, replace=False)
        route[i], route[j] = route[j], route[i]
    return route

def generate_unique_population(population_size, num_nodes):
    """
    Generate a unique population of individuals for a genetic algorithm.

    Each individual in the population represents a route in a graph, where the first node is fixed (0) and the 
    remaining nodes are a permutation of the other nodes in the graph. This function ensures that all individuals
    in the population are unique.

    Parameters:
        - population_size (int): The desired size of the population.
        - num_nodes (int): The number of nodes in the graph, including the starting node.

    Returns:
        - list of lists: A list of unique individuals, where each individual is represented as a list of node indices.
    """
    population = set()
    while len(population) < population_size:
        individual = [0] + list(np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, num_nodes)))
        population.add(tuple(individual))
    return [list(ind) for ind in population]


3. genetic_algorithm_trail:
# genetic_algorithm_trial.py

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
from tasks import evaluate_fitness, run_tournament_selection, perform_order_crossover, perform_mutation, generate_initial_population
from celery.result import AsyncResult

# Load the distance matrix
distance_matrix = pd.read_csv('city_distances.csv').to_numpy()

# Parameters
num_nodes = distance_matrix.shape[0]
population_size = 10000
num_tournaments = 4  # Number of tournaments to run
mutation_rate = 0.1
num_generations = 200
infeasible_penalty = 1e6  # Penalty for infeasible routes
stagnation_limit = 5  # Number of generations without improvement before regeneration

# Generate initial population asynchronously
initial_population_task = generate_initial_population.delay(population_size, num_nodes)
initial_population = initial_population_task.get()

# Initialize variables for tracking stagnation
best_calculate_fitness = int(1e6)
stagnation_counter = 0

# Start timing
start_time = time.time()

# Main GA loop
for generation in range(num_generations):
    # Evaluate fitness asynchronously
    calculate_fitness_tasks = [evaluate_fitness.delay(route) for route in population]
    calculate_fitness_values = [task.get() for task in calculate_fitness_tasks]

    # Check for stagnation
    current_best_calculate_fitness = np.min(calculate_fitness_values)
    if current_best_calculate_fitness < best_calculate_fitness:
        best_calculate_fitness = current_best_calculate_fitness
        stagnation_counter = 0
    else:
        stagnation_counter += 1

    # Regenerate population if stagnation limit is reached, keeping the best individual
    if stagnation_counter >= stagnation_limit:
        print(f"Regenerating population at generation {generation} due to stagnation")
        best_individual_task = evaluate_fitness.delay(population[np.argmin(calculate_fitness_values)])
        best_individual = best_individual_task.get()
        population_task = generate_initial_population.delay(population_size - 1, num_nodes)
        population = population_task.get()
        population.append(best_individual)
        stagnation_counter = 0
        continue  # Skip the rest of the loop for this generation

    # Selection asynchronously
    selection_task = run_tournament_selection.delay(population, calculate_fitness_values)
    selected = selection_task.get()

    # Crossover and mutation asynchronously
    crossover_mutation_tasks = [perform_order_crossover.delay(selected[i], selected[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(selected), 2)]
    crossover_results = [task.get() for task in crossover_mutation_tasks]
    mutated_offspring_tasks = [perform_mutation.delay(route, mutation_rate) for route in crossover_results]
    mutated_offspring = [task.get() for task in mutated_offspring_tasks]

    # Replacement: Replace the individuals that lost in the tournaments with the new offspring
    replacement_tasks = [evaluate_fitness.delay(route) for route in mutated_offspring]
    replacement_fitness_values = [task.get() for task in replacement_tasks]

    # Update population asynchronously
    for i, idx in enumerate(np.argsort(replacement_fitness_values)[::-1][:len(mutated_offspring)]):
        population[idx] = mutated_offspring[i]

    # Print best fitness asynchronously
    best_fitness_task = evaluate_fitness.delay(population[np.argmin(calculate_fitness_values)])
    current_best_calculate_fitness = best_fitness_task.get()
    print(f"Generation {generation}: Best calculate_fitness = {current_best_calculate_fitness}")

# End timing
end_time = time.time()

# Output the best solution
best_solution_task = evaluate_fitness.delay(population[np.argmin(calculate_fitness_values)])
best_solution = best_solution_task.get()
print("Best Solution:", best_solution)
print("Total Distance:", current_best_calculate_fitness)

# Calculate and print the execution time
execution_time = end_time - start_time
print("Execution Time:", execution_time, "seconds")


Additional Conetext:

I'm using Celery for asynchronous task execution.
The purpose of the project is to optimize routes using a genetic algorithm approach.
I've tried running the Celery worker with the celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info command and executing the genetic_algorithm_trial.py file in a separate terminal, but I keep encountering the mentioned error.

Request:
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error and successfully retrieve the initial population asynchronously using Celery. Thank you in advance for your help!

Does this answer your question? kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: User is not JSON serializable
